# SQL (Redshift) SELECT COUNT from CSV column

Tags: count, csv, redshift

Hi exchange community,

**Problem statement and details:**
I am trying to query a column that contains CSV data to produce a count of instances of each value in the table.  There are a total of 14 possible values in the CSV data. These are static and will never change. Each record contains at least one value in the CSV column but may contain up to all 14 values. Each value may only appear at most once in the CSV column per record.

**Sample Data from Pets column:**
cat, dog fish, rat
dog
dog, cat horse, ferret, zebra
dog, cat, alligator, bear, fish, bird

**what have i tried?**
I've gotten as far as being able to return a view that contains a single record with columns containing a count for the number of instances. It's close to what I need, I just need to have this transposed (rows <-> columns).  any ideas?

```
SELECT 
    count(case when vet.pets like '%dog%' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS dog
    ,  count(case when vet.pets like '%cat%' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as cat
    ,  count(case when vet.pets like '%rat%' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as rat
    ,  count(case when vet.pets like '%bird%' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as bird
    ,  count(case when vet.pets like '%fish%' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as fish
    ,  count(case when vet.pets like '%hamster%' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as hamster
    ,  count(case when vet.pets like '%ferret%' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as ferret
    ,  count(case when vet.pets like '%horse%' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as horse
    ,  count(case when vet.pets like '%zebra%' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as zebra
    ,  count(case when vet.pets like '%bear%' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as bear
    ,  count(case when vet.pets like '%alligator%' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as alligator
    ,  count(case when vet.pets like '%sugar_glider%' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as sugar_glider
    ,  count(case when vet.pets like '%tiger%' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)  as tiger
    ,  count(case when vet.pets like '%rock%' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as rock
    FROM vet
```

This produces:

> dog | cat | rat | bird | fish | hamster | ferret | horse | zebra |
>   bear | alligator | sugar_glider | tiger | rock
>       3 | 5 | 2 | 6 | 8 | 1 | 8 | 5 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 4 | 2

But I need it in the format:

> ```
> dog | 3
> cat | 5
> rat | 2
> bird | 6
> fish | 8
> hamster | 1
> ferret | 8
> horse | 5
> zebra | 1
> bear | 3
> alligator | 2
> sugar_glider | 2
> tiger | 4
> rock | 2
> ```

Comment: Create (temporary) table with patterns (including percent signs) and join it to your table by `vet.pets LIKE patterns.pattern`. Remember that you will count NOT the amount of values in CSV, you will count the amount of CSVs which contains at least one (but may be more) pattern value(s) in column value (i.e. `'cat'` against `'cat,dog,cat'` will be counted once, not twice). If you need strictly amount you must summarise `(LENGTH(vet.pets) - LENGTH(REPLACE(vet.pets, patterns.pattern, '')))/LENGTH(patterns.pattern)` (in this case pattern must be without percent signs).

Answer (score 1):

Was able to figure this out by unioning my individual count statements.

```
SELECT 'dog' as 'animal', count(case when vet.pets like '%dog%' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'count' FROM vet
UNION ALL
SELECT 'cat' as 'animal',  count(case when vet.pets like '%cat%' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'count' FROM vet
UNION ALL
etc.
```

Comment: why don't you show the query and let other people benefit from it too?

Comment: @MarcelloMiorelli - added query snippet above